# hook_field_schema not being used

Tags: 7, hooks, entities

I'm trying to create a field with an additional property (or column) to define an extra relationship to a taxonomy term.

I have this in my module file:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_info().
 */
function emtr_field_info() {
    return array(
        // We name our field as the associative name of the array.
        'field_emtr_denominations' => array(
            'label' => t('Denominations'),
            'description' => t('Field linked to target entity as well as denomination taxonomy term holding denomnation value.'),
            'default_widget' => 'number',
            'default_formatter' => 'number_decimal',
        ),
    );
}
```

And this in my install file:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_schema().
 */
function emtr_field_schema($field) {
    $columns = array(
        'denomination_value' => array(
            'type' => 'int',
            'not null' => FALSE,
        ),
        'denomination_tid' => array(
            'type' => 'int',
            'not null' => TRUE,
            'default' => 0,
        ),
    );
    $indexes = array(
        'denomination_tid' => array('denomination_tid'),
    );
    return array(
        'columns' => $columns,
        'indexes' => $indexes,
    );
}

/**
 * Implements hook_enable().
 */
function emtr_enable() {

    field_cache_clear();
    field_associate_fields('emtr');

    if (field_info_field('emtr_denominations')) return;

    // Create a field for denominations to be used by safe checks and till reads
    $field = array(
        'field_name' => 'emtr_denominations',
        'type' => 'field_emtr_denominations',
        'cardinality' => FIELD_CARDINALITY_UNLIMITED,
        'translatable' => FALSE,
    );
    field_create_field($field);

    // Attach the emtr_denominations reference field to safe checks instance
    $instance = array(
        'field_name' => 'emtr_denominations',
        'entity_type' => 'emtr_safe_check',
        'bundle' => 'emtr_safe_check',
        'label' => 'Denominations',
        'required' => false,
        'widget' => array(
            'type' => 'number'
        ),
        'settings' => array(
            'target_type' => 'emtr_safe_check',
            'handler_settings' => array('target_bundles' => NULL),
        ),
        'display' => array(
            'default' => array('label' => 'inline', 'type' => 'number_integer'),
        ),
    );
    field_create_instance($instance);
}
```

But after uninstalling and re-enabling my module (drush devel-reinstall emtr -y
) a table called field_data_emtr_denominations is created but it does not have my 2 custom columns.

At what point in this process should I tell Drupal to use my custom field_schema?

Comment: I'm not sure what I've done but after a couple more hours repeatedly installing and uninstalling my module it started working. I think maybe there was a conflict with another field created though the field UI but I'm not entirely sure. But for future reference the above code is now working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove function `emtr_enable()` out of the `.install` file, and place its code in a more proper hook where the field is meaningful to be created, like for instance `hook_node_type_insert()` or EntityAPIController-derived class for your entity bundle, etc.  It depends on what one wants to achieve really.

Comment: emtr_enable implements hook_enable. I would put the code in there in hook_install however I understood that that would lead to problems as my hook_field_schema would not have run when the hook_install runs. Hook enable can only live in the modules install file so I can't move that anywhere else.